# Long Date Format on Javascript - PDF Stamp

Tags: javascript, date-format

New to this, I am creating an "interactive" stamp that needs the "long date format" on a PDF stamp.

Currently, this is the code I have:

```js
var builder = 
{
 // These map to Text Fields in the Stamp
 textBoxes :
 [
  { field:"CheckedBy", description:"By:", default:function() { return ""; } },
  { field:"ProjectNumber", description:"ProjectNumber", default:function() { return ""; } },
  { field:"Date", description:"Date:", default:function() 
   {  
    var curDate = new Date();
    return (curDate.getMonth() + 1) + "." + curDate.getDate() + "," + curDate.getFullYear();
   } 
 
  }
 ],
 // This maps to a Radio Group in the PDF named 'Status'
 radioGroup : "Status", 
 radioButtons :
 [
  // value maps to the 'Choice' of each radio button in the group, description will show on the dialog
  { value:"Reviewed", description:"Reviewed" },
  { value:"ReviseasNoted", description:"Revise as Noted" },
  { value:"ReviseandResubmit", description:"Revise and Resubmit" },
  { value:"NotReviewed", description:"Not Reviewed" },
 ],
 radioErrorMsg : "Please select a status"
}
```

This returns the date 08.09,2018 but I need to change the date format so it is "Sep. 05, 2018" I have tried numerous suggestions but I can seem to get it to work. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where do you get the `05` in `Sep. 05` from `08.09,2018`?

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example of the date format that returns.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to do this. To achieve what you are after you can do this:

`let dateToday = new Date()
moment(dateToday).format("MMM. DD, YYYY")`

Comment: What did you try doing? What error is happening? verified it with moment, so I'm not sure what is wrong.